# Как форматировать ячейки при вводе данных?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

1. Допустим я ввожу дату: **"7/24/2018 17:49:21"**. При этом хочу, чтобы в гугл-таблице она отображалась: **"24.07"** (т.е. в формате число и месяц).
2. Допустим я ввожу любые данные, и хочу чтобы после ввода клетка с данными покрасилась (заливка) в синий цвет.

Это возможно сделать?

p.s. Я так понимаю, что данные нужно вводить в виде скрипта или нет?

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно вводить данные в формате '2018-08-17 17:49:21' и в вкладке 'другие форматы' выбрать как отображать дату. 
   (Что бы автоматично вводить дату то можно использовать функцию 'new Date();' в google apps scripts)
2. Можно использовать Условное форматирование. Выбери ячейку > ПКМ > Условное форматирование > Применить к диапазону >  Ячейка с данными > выбрать цвет.